# How to send parametrs to the url in struts.xml

Tags: struts2

Hi any body know how to send parametrs to the url in struts.xml

mycode is

```
<action name="deleteDocDetails" class="com.myDrDirect.doctor.action.DoctorEditAction"  
      method="deleteSingleDoctor">
   <result name="success" type="redirect">salesManDoctorhome </result>
 </action>
```

i want to pass `searchIndicator=Allsearch&search=&pageLink=doctor` these variable to this parameter.

i want my url to be like this `salesManDoctorhome?searchIndicator=Allsearch&search=&pageLink=doctor`

i have already tried this

```
<action name="deleteDocDetails" class="com.myDrDirect.doctor.action.DoctorEditAction"
  method="deleteSingleDoctor">
 <result name="success" type="redirect">salesManDoctorhome </result>
        <param name="searchIndicator">Allsearch</param>
        <param name="pageLink">doctor</param>
 </action>
```

But it is not working..
the variable i am sending is static variable. I am using struts2 in my project

Comment: what is not working and what is `salesManDoctorhome`?

Comment: its hard to provide any answer without any furthur information

Comment: salesManDoctorhome is an action name in my struts.xml

Comment: if you are redirecting to same application scope do not go with `redirect` and use `redirectAction` instead which is more flexible, for details refer to the documents. http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/redirect-action-result.html

Comment: Thanks let me check whether it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may want use variable in url, you may have {variable name} this variable must have public get method in action.

Comment: Sry, forget $ before it also, like ${}